# Orthogonal Basis for Operators

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This idea might sound strange but I was wondering if there is a notion of constructing operators of certain types using an linear sum of a set of orthogonal operators. That is, just like functions can be written as infinite sums of trig functions (Fourier) or polynomials (Taylor), can we construct a set of operators that might span some space of operators?
for example $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\frac {d^ny}{dx} = O(y(x))$$ where $O(y(x))$ is a operator acting on $y$.
Thanks

Comment: one of my professors hinted at an idea of differential equations  looking for functions over infinte-dimensional vector spaces, i assume this is what it would look like

Comment: what are these spaces called? how do I read about them cuz I could not find them online.

Comment: @Yonahshmalo the keywords you want are "Lp" spaces or "Sobolev" spaces.